# C# Hidden Program Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, timer, hidden

I've created a C# console application and changed the output type to a Windows Application in `Project > Project Properties` to create a hidden program.

My main method looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(); // Initialize a timer
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(runProgram); // to call method runProgram
    timer.Interval = 10000; // every 10 seconds
    timer.AutoReset = true; // which auto-resets
    timer.Enabled = true; // Enable timer
    timer.Start(); // Start timer
    Console.ReadLine(); // Prevent program from terminating
}
```

The program should be hidden and call the method `runProgram` every 10 seconds.

When I compile this as a Console Application it works fine. But when I try to compile as a Windows Application it doesn't work. My guess is the timer is not working when compiled as a Windows Application.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean compiling as a windows application?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @SpaceSteak Project Properties> Application > output Type: to "Windows Application"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `Console.ReadLine();` without a console.

Instead, you should call either `Application.Run()` (to run a message loop) or `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)` (to hang forever).